# Create a vector containt 200 times a random sample of 20 in R

Tags: r, for-loop, random

I have to create a vector which contains 200 times a random sample of 20 numbers (always number 1 to 20 but in a random order). I tried to do this with a for loop and with sample(20) but it did not work. can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want the same sample (of 20 numbers) repeated 200 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
unlist(lapply(1:200, function(x) sample(1:20)))
```

or

```
c(sapply(1:200,\(x) sample(1:20)))
```

The result is 4000 elements long, which I think is what you want (200 consecutive samples of 1:20)

Comment: sorry, it is 4000, that was just a typo!! :)

Comment: thanks it works, perfect!!

Comment: it works, but @ThomasIsCoding answer seems like the way to go!. :)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `replicate` + `sample`

```
replicate(200, sample(20))
```

which works in an easy way than `for` loops